# troubles with PHP setlocale and iso-8859-1 encoding

Tags: php, encoding, strftime, setlocale

I have created a website using `iso-8859-1` encoding, and I want to display the date in French.

Here is the file I use for test :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.iso88591"); echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y."); ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

When I open this file I get : `Thursday 08 August 2013.` instead of `Jeudi 08 Août 2013.` (french).

I have tried using `UTF-8` and it works correctly but it is not what I want...

I have checked the language packages installed on my server and everything seems correct :

```
server$ sudo locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
français
french
fr_FR
fr_FR.iso88591
fr_FR.utf8
POSIX
```

If you have any ideas to solve this problem it would be very cool.

**EDIT :** typos corrected !

Comment: Do you mean setlocale?

Comment: Yes I have made a mistake, I mean `setlocale`.

Answer (score 2):

You had typos.
Change the "setlocal" and "8895-1"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8895-1"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php setlocal(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.iso88951"); echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y."); ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

to "setlocale" and "8859-1", respectively.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
    <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"/>
    </head>
    <body>
      <?php setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.iso88591"); echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y."); ?>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Oh yes, sorry for that too... I correct these (huge) mistakes but the problem still the same...

Answer (score 0):

Like I pointed out in my comment, it should be [setlocale](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php), not setlocal.

A quick Google search pointed me to [this website](http://www.astro.rug.nl/cgi-bin/man-cgi?setlocale) which indicates that you should be doing

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.ISO-8859-1");
```

instead of

```
setlocal(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.iso88951");
```

**EDIT :**

Try this:

```
<?php
setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR.iso88591");
setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, 'C');
echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y.");
?>
```

I haven't tried it but it's worth a shot.

Comment: It does not work. I think that the string has to be the same as one of the `locale` ouput...

Comment: I edited my post. It's worth a shot. If it's not it then I'm simply out of clues, sorry.

Answer (score -1):

Typo in your code (setlocal should be setlocale):

```
<?php setlocale(LC_ALL, "fr_FR"); echo strftime("%A %d %B %Y."); ?>
```

Also make sure the French locale is available on your system:

```
locale -a
```

To see what locales are available (unix).

Comment: Can't test it locally for you in French.